# Disable an entire Row in AR Invoice Lines (AEF)

Tags: acumatica

I know it is possible to enable/disable particular fields progrmmatically. Is it also possible to disable editing of the entire row? I am referring to the Transactions (ARTran) in the Invoice Entry screen. I would want to disable changing any values in the line on particular conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled method has an overload that works on all fields of a row.

```
public class SOInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
{
    protected virtual void ARTran_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        ARTran row = e.Row as ARTran;

        if (row == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool myCondition = false;
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(Base.Caches[typeof(ARTran)], row, myCondition);
    }
}
```

Comment: One gotcha is if you set the row to true it will enable all fields regardless of each fields enabled settings. I think in that scenario you simply don't call SetEnable if you want the row back to its original enabled form.